# Background color button same as background color div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let me explain it in a few words.
I have a menu with different colored buttons. For example When I mouseover/click button A (=blue e.g.) I want the bgcolor of the div also turning blue.
When I `mouseover/click` button B (`=green`) I want the `bgcolor` of the div also turning green.

Is there a possibility to this with a simple script?

[image]

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").hover(function () {
    $(this).parents("navigatie").css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
},

function () {
    $(this).parents("navigatie").css("background-color", "white");
});
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<?php include("header.php");?>

<div id="navigatie">
    <center>
        <button class="A">Button A</button>
        <button class="B">Button B</button>
    </center>
</div>

<div id="tekst">

BLABLABLA

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

/*** CSS ***/

```
navigatie {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    transition:all 0.4s ease;
}

button {
    width:75px;
    height:50px;
    border-style:none;
    top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    color:white;
    border: solid 1px white;
}
.A {
    background-color:blue;
}
.B {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:limegreen;
}
```

Comment: You should use simple jquery for this. Give us some of your code please.

Comment: Good where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("button").hover(function () {
    $(this).parents("div").css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
},

function () {
    $(this).parents("div").css("background-color", "white");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/96wa2zva/)

---

Full code after fix as per what you provided in your edit:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
navigatie {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    transition:all 0.4s ease;
}

button {
    width:75px;
    height:50px;
    border-style:none;
    top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    color:white;
    border: solid 1px white;
}
.A {
    background-color:blue;
}
.B {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:limegreen;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").hover(function () {
        $(this).parents("#navigatie").css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
    },

    function () {
        $(this).parents("#navigatie").css("background-color", "white");
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<?php include("header.php");?>

<div id="navigatie">
    <center>
        <button class="A">Button A</button>
        <button class="B">Button B</button>
    </center>
</div>

<div id="tekst">

BLABLABLA

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it but it just doesnt work inside my website. I put the javascript between the headtags but it just doesnt hover.

Comment: @Jorus Try placing the code within `$(document).ready()` code at the end of ur page. The sequence in which ur code and elements are being loaded and executed might be the reason.

Comment: Yeah already tried it, but i think i did it wrong. `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").hover(function () {
    $(this).parents("navigatie").css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
},

function () {
    $(this).parents("navigatie").css("background-color", "white");
});
    });
</script>`

Comment: Can you add ur html codes to ur question? will be easier to help :)

Comment: Added (see top screen)

Comment: @Jorus The mistake is at `$(this).parents("navigatie")` when u modified the code. Jquery tries to find the element `navigatie` (it was `div` before). As there are no element with that name, it highlights nothing. To make the code work, use `$(this).parents("#navigatie")`, which will locate by ID rather than element.

Comment: OMG SERIOUS? Just a hashtag missing?! Lmfao. Thanks dude!

Comment: Sure i will, but one last thing. Is it easy to combine the hover effect with a click? So when I hover the button, the background is temporarily and when I click the background will stay.

Comment: Sure, [here is the JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/s2tv0pf4/) to the updated code :D

Answer (score 1):

Use this for start you can enhance this with your own coding logic.

```js
$('input:button').each(function() {


  var color = $(this).attr("data-color");
  $(this).css("background-color", color);


});





$('input:button').click(function() {
  var color = $(this).attr("data-color")
  $('#wrapper').css("background-color", color);

});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #d0e4fe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

  <input type="button" name="color" data-color="red" value="Red">
  <input type="button" name="color" data-color="green" value="Green">
  <input type="button" name="color" data-color="purple" value="Purple">
  <input type="button" name="color" data-color="#d0e4fe" value="Default">

  </div>
```

Comment: Isnt it just possible to solve this with "inherit" ? I would like to post some code but i don't know how -.-

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery:

```
$("#[id]").hover(function({
  $("#[id]").css({"[propertyname]":"[value]","[propertyname]":"[value]",...});
```

/*

Fill the brackets with the correct ids / classes and property names and values.
If you want to change the background on a click then replace .hover   with   .click

*/

If anyone finds something I did wrong or if there is a better way to do it, please correct me or let me know! I'm always open to better ideas! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use CSS, there's only two ways of changing the style of an element through the state of another:

The targeted element must either be a child of the element receiving a state change, or a direct sibling (right underneath).

Using CSS's "+" selector, you can affect the next sibling element.
In your case this could be used to achieve this effect:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrptjoh9/

The action occurs here:

```
.a .button:hover + .bg {
    background: red;
}

.b .button:hover + .bg {
    background: blue;
}
```

Although this requires the button and background elements to be siblings.

Comment: Thanks all! I think the solutions of Ahs N and leuquim will help me further.

Comment: Well it was to good to be true. It just doesnt work in my website. Let me be more specific (sorry but i just dont know how to add code). I have one wide div (called .navigation) with in it a menu of different blocks with all different sizes (kind of mosaic). When i mouseover/click a button I want the "div .navigation" will get the same color as the button.

Comment: The jsfiddle you've attached seems to be working fine, the background color changes as you hover each link. What am I missing? What isn't working?

Comment: I just don't get the javascript from jsfiddle working, i now have this:  `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").hover(function () {
    $(this).parents("navigatie").css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
},

function () {
    $(this).parents("navigatie").css("background-color", "white");
});
    });
</script>`

Comment: There's no JS in the fiddle you've attached.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JavaScript:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btnA');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var event = e || window.event,
      target = event.target,
      parent = target.parentNode,
      color = parent.style.backgroundColor;
  if(color === 'blue') {
     parent.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  } else {
     parent.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
});
btn.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  var event = e || window.event,
      target = event.target,
      parent = target.parentNode;
  parent.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});
btn.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  var event = e || window.event,
      target = event.target,
      parent = target.parentNode;
  parent.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});
```

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container button{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button id="btnA">Button A</button>
</div>
```